# How to display a message on android?

Tags: java, android, label

How I can display a message for a few seconds without using Toast on Android?
It's possible to use label for this case?

Comment: use a custom Dialog with a Handler's postDelayed()

Answer (score 0):

create a pop-up screen and start counter when pop-up created. When counter ends, kill pop-up.
You can use AlertDialog.Builder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a message for sometime then use of Toast is a better approach.You can customize the Toast message as per your need so that it will look like a real pop up message.

### Java code

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_layout,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();

            }
        });
```

### toast_custom_layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#DAAA"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android1:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent"
        android1:src="@drawable/red_heart" />

    <TextView
        android1:id="@+id/textView1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent"
        android1:text="This is custom Toast message"
        android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```